# Can I use same content for landing page?

Tags: seo

I have a product based website, Im planing to replicate the product page of the website as a separate landing page, so that i can have https://xxxxxx/product as a main website, and http://product.com/ as a landing page. I wan both, main site as well as landing pages to be top in google. Planning to work on SEO for both URL. Kindly suggest

Comment: planning to replicate..... why?

Answer (score 2):

***In Short... No, nope, nah, nay, negative, veto, non, nein***

*Landing pages are not for Google or Bing, PERIOD.*

Google and Bing will not rank duplicate pages and enough unique but similar pages can result in negative SEO which will affect your rankings on the entire domain.

If you want landing pages such as:

- *Web Design in Bournemouth*
- *Web Design in Poole*
- *Web Design in Dorset*

Or

- *Bits and Bobs in Aqua*
- *Bits and Bobs in Blue*
- *Bits and Bobs in Navy Blue*

Then you will either need to have unique content, but it should be noted that Google dislike's too many similar pages regardless if the content is different. So while a few may not hurt, too many of them will.

*Marketing*

Your only choice if you want these type of pages is to use some form of advertising that will send visitors to those types of pages. Most companies use tailored landing pages using Google or Bing's Advertising networks. You should also use canonical pages or no-index on those pages.